# Alternating images with a timer using java

Tags: java, image, loops, timer, alternate

Since I'm not a CS major, I'm having some difficulties translating my programming wishes into an actual program. 
What it basically boils down to is the following: how can I alternate an image on a label, showing each image for an amount of tim specific for each image.

So: say I've images A and B; I'd like the user to see A for 1000ms and B for 200ms. This keeps on looping until a user presses a certain key.

Now, I'm able to load an image onto a panel, quite easily even, and I've managed to catch user input using KeyListener and stuff, which all works quite nicely and alot easier then I had expected. I also know how to use looping constructs like while, for and do..while, but this timer business is shady.

I see all kinds of stuff using threads and what not, I really don't need that. This is not about efficient programming or good code, it's simply about demonstrating something.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I can think of many CS majors that would have difficulty translating their programming wishes into actual programs - don't let that discourage you in the slightest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a [`SwingWorker<Void, Void>`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html). The doInBackground method of the SwingWorker should look like this :

```
@Override
protected Void doInBackground() {
    try {
        while (true) {
            displayImage(imageA);
            Thread.sleep(1000L);
            if (isCancelled()) {
                return null;
            }
            displayImage(imageB);
            Thread.sleep(200L);
            if (isCancelled()) {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // ignore
    }
    return null;
}

private void displayImage(final Icon image) {
    SwingUtilituies.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // display the image in the panel
        }
    });
}
```

The keylistener should simply cancel the SwingWorker.

Comment: I see, I hadn't heard of SwingWorker, I'm digging into this now. Thanks.

Comment: Something I don't understand. I've my class extending SwingWorker. I've overriden the doInBackground() and implemented the displayImage method in the way you described. 
In my constructor I'm creating a a JFrame with a JLabel, load some images and call this.execute();, alas, nothing seems to happen. I get presented with the frame, but nothing further. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Here's something that might be a good example:
http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Development-Class/UsejavautilTimertoscheduleatasktoexecuteonce5secondshavepassed.htm

I can try to explain the code if it appears confusing

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing necessarily inefficient about using threads when threads are the right tool for the job.

In this case, it would not be unreasonable to create a new class that implements `Runnable`, which holds a reference to the label you wish to change the image on.

This means that the image could be changed without causing waits on the main application that would cause it to hang until it was done.

You would want to avoid 'Busy Loops' [basically, a while loop with no Thread.sleep() within it], and look to see if there is any needed thread exit criteria

Comment: I'm not saying anything is inefficient; I'm saying I'm not looking for efficiency. It's just that learning to work with threading is really out of scope for what I'm trying to accomplish here: some visual aid(e?)s for an experiment in an experimental psychology course I'm taking as a sidestep to neurology. So, basically, anything fancy is too much. Clean code or design patterns are of no importance whatsoever, it just needs to run one time, after which it'll be thrown out hehe

Unless, of course, threading is a necessity, I'll avoid the extra workload ;)

Comment: But, I'll look into Runnable et cetera, as it seems to be the only way to avoid my application from 'hanging'. Which means it won't respond to key presses, right?

Comment: knowledge about Runnables is a good idea, and correct usage will indeed prevent it not responding to keypresses. JB Nizet's SwingWorker looks a better place to start in this case, though