# Problems with a SwingWorker

Tags: java, image, swing, jlabel, swingworker

I'm trying to get a SwingWorker to work.
I've the following code at the moment:

```
public class ImageWorker extends SwingWorker<Void, Void> implements KeyListener
{   
private JLabel imageLabel;
private ImageIcon basicImage; 
private ImageIcon whiteImage;  
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    new ImageWorker();      
}

public ImageWorker()
{
    final JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    imageLabel = new JLabel();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(400, 400);
    frame.getContentPane().add(imageLabel);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    try
    {
        basicImage = new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(new File("src\\img\\basis1.jpg")).getScaledInstance(1024, 768, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH));
        whiteImage = new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(new File("src\\img\\wit.jpg")).getScaledInstance(1024, 768, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH));       
    }
    catch(IOException ex)
    {
        ex.getMessage();
    }
    this.execute();

}

@Override
protected Void doInBackground() 
{
    try
    {
        while (true)
        {
            displayImage(basicImage);
            Thread.sleep(1000L);
            if(isCancelled())
                return null;
        }
    }
    catch(InterruptedException e)
    {
        e.getMessage();
    }
    return null;
}

private void displayImage(final Icon image)
{
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
    {
        public void run()
        {
            imageLabel.setIcon(image);
        }
    });     
}
```

I was expecting the images to appear in the JLabel, but I only see the JFrame popping up. The files are loaded correctly Ive tested that in another setup.
Any pointers?

Comment: What exactly are you doing here that requires a `SwingWorker`? It's meant to be used in situations where you're doing something intensive in the background but want the result to be displayed in the UI and so, need to do something in the `Event Dispatch Thread`- like loading images over the network. Here it looks like you're just displaying the images continuously. Maybe if you explain what you want to achieve, you'll get a good answer.

Comment: I'm not doing anything intesive, I'm just trying to alternate some images on a JLabel, until a user presses a key. but since I'm not a programmer I have no idea where to start. I was told a SwingWorker would be an easy place to start, since neither efficiency or good code are important. It;s a one time use for a presentation for some course I'm taking (not CS related obviously). I'm looking for quick n dirty hehe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5179569/alternating-images-with-a-timer-using-java

Comment: Ok, that helps. Let me go over this again.

Comment: But whether a SwingWorker is overkill or not isn't important. If it'll do the job, it does the job.  Edit: Cheers :)

Comment: @ZedLep The mix of a SwingWorker and the SwingUtilities.invokeLater method is very unusual.  The point of SwingWorker is it provides methods that run on the EDT, preventing you from needing to do things like call invokeLater.

Comment: I really don't care about best practices, it's a one time 5 minute use :( I just want to get the images alternating hehe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example using a `Timer` rather than using the `SwingWorker` which really isn't appropriate to your situation. Note that it's not too different from your existing code.

```
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class ImageWorker implements KeyListener
{
    private JLabel imageLabel;
    private ImageIcon basicImage;
    private ImageIcon whiteImage;
    private boolean isBasic =  true;
    private int delay = 1000; //milliseconds
    private Timer timer;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new ImageWorker();
    }

    public ImageWorker()
    {
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        imageLabel = new JLabel();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(400, 400);
        frame.getContentPane().add(imageLabel);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        try
        {
            basicImage = new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(new File("src\\img\\basis1.jpg")).getScaledInstance(1024, 768, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH));
            whiteImage = new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(new File("src\\img\\wit.jpg")).getScaledInstance(1024, 768, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH));       
        }
        catch (IOException ex)
        {
            ex.getMessage();
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        frame.addKeyListener(this);
        ActionListener taskPerformer = new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                if(isBasic) {
                    //display basic image
                    imageLabel.setIcon(basicImage);
                }
                else {
                    //display white image
                    imageLabel.setIcon(whiteImage);
                }

                //toggle the flag
                isBasic = !isBasic;
            }
        };
        //use a timer instead of SwingWorker
        timer = new Timer(delay, taskPerformer);
        timer.start();

    }



    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e)
    {
        //key pressed, we want to stop toggling so stop the timer
        timer.stop();
        //do whatever else you were doing to set the value for isCancelled();
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

Comment: One of the trickiest problems you might run into is that you should perform any GUI related operations (changing size, color etc) in the `Event Dispatch Thread`. If you use a normal timer (`java.util.Timer`), the timeout events will not trigger a callback in the GUI thread which is problematic for a Swing app. Which is why, if you notice, we want to use the `javax.swing.Timer` which will call back in the GUI thread so you can safely perform GUI operations.

Comment: Also note that your original code did work for me - at least to the point that I could see an image. So if you still have problems, it's probably a problem with the path you're providing for your images. A better and more portable way would be to [load the image as a resource](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/icon.html).

Comment: Wow, this is exactly what I was looking for :) I can easily make some change to this to taylor for my needs. Thank you very very much!!!

Comment: @ZedLep - Glad it helped! I've made two minor edits though; I had forgotten to register the key listener (`frame.addKeyListener(this);`) so the original code wouldn't have ever stopped toggling images. I've also added a call to `#printStackTrace()` that will display the stacktrace for an exception so you can debug easily.

Comment: Yeah, I figured :) Thanks anyway =) Seeing I started Java yesterday (when we decided to do this particular experiment) and we're doing the experiment tomorrow I'm not doing too bad I think hehe

Answer (score 1):

A `SwingWorker` is not appropriate for your situation look into a `Timer` in the swing package.  Here is a link to the API: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html

You have the timer run and change an image every second since that is what you need.

Also, whenever you have exceptions, print out a stacktrace or the message at least.  Otherwise you won't know if an exception occurs and is caught.

Comment: @jzd Does setIcon trigger a repaint or does he need to call that explicitly? I'm not sure off the top of my head.

Comment: I still need to be able to cancel running by pressing a key, which I know how to do. But I don't have the time (nor wish) to learn the nuts and bolts of Java, so I have been working with this SwingWorker for some hours, but without alot of luck. Being overkill or not I'd like to pursue this, hence the question.

Comment: @ZedLep, you are wasting your time messing with SwingWorker, use a Timer.  Keep a reference to it and you can cancel it when needed.

Comment: @gcooney, a call to repaint might be needed, but the real issue is that SwingWorker is not what is needed to repeat an action based on a time interval, that is exactly what Timer is designed for and what should be used instead.

Comment: Ok, I'll look into that then :)

Comment: To be honest I have no idea what to do now? Threads? Timers? I need threads to be able to stop the alternating by pressing a key isn't?

Comment: @ZedLep, Timer will take care of the need for Threads.  You need a KeyListener to complete an action based on a key event, not a thread.